# condition for nonexpansivity of a square matrix?

Tags: convex-optimization

suppose $X=R^{n}$ and let $N \in R^{n \times n}$ be a matrix. Show that N is nonexpansive if and only if $\lambda_{max}(N^T N)\leq 1$.

For showing nonexpansiveness we must show that
$(\forall x \in X) (\forall y \in X)  \hspace{5mm} ||Nx-Ny|| \leq ||x-y||$. But how can I relate this definition to the largest eigenvalue.

Any help or references will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Assume for a second that $N$ is an orthogonal matrix, with eigenvectors $(x_n)_n$ and corresponding eigenvalues $(\lambda_n)_n$, which we can without the loss of generality assume to satisfy
$$
|\lambda_1| \ge |\lambda_2| \ge \ldots \ge |\lambda_n|.
$$

Therefore, for any $u \in X$, we have
$$
\begin{split}
\|Au\|
 &= \left\|A\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k x_k\right)\right\| \\
 &= \left\|\sum_{k=1}^n a_k A x_k \right\| \\
 &= \left\|\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \lambda_k x_k \right\| \\
 &\le \left\|\sum_{k=1}^n a_k x_k \right\| |\lambda_1 | \\
 &\le |\lambda_1| \left\|u\right\|
\end{split}
$$

For reference, $|\lambda_1|$ is called the *operator norm* of $A$.